# Various options failing to drop my database tables with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement a function that drops all my database tables in Python's sqlalchemy.

My expected result is a clean database, the equivalent of going into my MySQL Workbench, selecting all 3 tables in my database and clicking "Drop 3 Tables".

Here's what I've tried:

(1)

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/scrapes?charset=utf8', echo=False)

meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = engine
meta.drop_all()
```

Result: Nothing happens. My db stays the same.

(2)

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.drop_all()
```

Result: "sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: MetaData object is not bound to an Engine or Connection.  Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against."

(3)

```
# This worked a few days ago, I think
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.drop_all()
```

Result: Nothing happens!

(4)

```
tables = Base.metadata.sorted_tables
for table in tables:
    engine.execute(table.delete())
```

Result: "sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`scrapes`.`page`, CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `query` (`id`))')
[SQL: DELETE FROM query]"

Note I recently changed **one** column in **one** of the classes defining my tables. Maybe that has something to do with it. I just added `created_date = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())`

Now sure I can just drop the tables from my workbench, but I want to do it *programmatically* so I can instruct my server to do it from my frontend with the click of a button.

Will one of these options work with a little modification? I also tested `drop tables from workbench -> recreate tables using new definitions -> attempt to drop tables again`, none of them worked. Help please!